# Problemas al llamar un botón estático desde un Fragment

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos botones estáticos en mi `Adapter` de `RecyclerView` en ocultos, lo que intento es que cuando este en un `Fragment` un botón sea oculto y otro visible, y al revés desde el otro `Fragment`, pero siempre recibo:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

sé que lo que me quiere decir que el objeto no tiene referencia y por lo tanto es null, pero no entiendo el por qué..

Así lo tengo en el `adapter`

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public static Button favButton, favQuitar;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        favButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favButton);
        favQuitar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favQuitar);
    }
}
```

Y así en mi `Fragment` (utilizo los `Fragment` para crear un `TabView`)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,
            container, false);


    favButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    favQuitar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;}
```

en el `xml` de mi `Adapter` ambos están `gone`, para obtener el botón en mi `Fragment` realizo *Static import constans* y selecciono mi `Adapter` creo que es lo correcto... Alguien me puede decir ¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: Has definido los botones en el codigo del fragment? En el metodo "onCreateView" haces uso de los botones "favButton" y "favQuitar" pero en ninguna parte se ve como los defines y buscas la view del boton.

Comment: R.id.favButton y R.id.favQuitar se encuentran en el layout que carga onCreateViewHolder() , es así? @UserNameYo

Comment: Se encuentran en el `layout` del `adapter` y no en el `fragment` @Jorgesys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que comentas es obviamente porque no encuentra la referencia de la vista, por lo tanto no puede llamar un método de una instancia null.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

En este caso tratas de cambiar propiedades de elementos que se encuentran dentro de tu `Adapter` desde el `Fragment`, **lo correcto es que las propiedades de los elementos sean modificadas dentro del mismo `Adapter`, esto cuando se llama el método `onBindViewHolder()`**:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AppTourViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Si deseas que al inicio tengan estas propiedades,

```
 favButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 favQuitar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

define por default estas propiedades en el layout del `Adapter`.